# How do you 'do something' to every element in a list except that one index?

Tags: c#

I created a list of 40 buttons, each of these buttons have an 'int counter' that counts up incrementally to 5 whenever pressed.

If I hit button 1, the other button's counter will reset and become 0, but the button I hit can now increase to 2, 3, 4, 5.

How would you loop the list in a way that doesn't also reset the button being pressed?

Button itself is a class, and I have a ButtonManager that contains List< Button > Buttons

The method I tried requires System.Linq where I filtered the list of the 39 non-pressed buttons into another set of list and make sure the counter for them are 0 for each press.  That solution feels way too inefficient.  This is supposed to be made for a game.

Comment: Are you using Windows forms? Web?

Comment: Your solution actually sounds like a normal way of doing this (in terms of objects in a list). If you post the code, people will have a basis to comment on.

Comment: You can use linq. Something like `foreach(Button button in Buttons.Where(p=>p!=pressedButton)){ button.Counter = 0;}`. The exact implementation depends on what framework you are using for the GUI, but this is the pattern.

Comment: @dmedine Thanks for showing me the more elegant way of writing it.  That was what I did before, but yours were more compact.
In the end, I gave my brain a good night rest and settled with:

[ButtonManager.cs]
if(triggered) { button.pressedButton = true; } else { button.pressedButton = false; } 

[Button.cs]
public void Update() { if(pressedButton) { Counter++; } else { Counter = 0; } }

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is windows Forms, every button can have the same handler:

```
private void AnyButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
  buttonManager.Increment(sender as Button);
}
```

And the button manager can:

```
public void Increment(Button clicked){
  _buttons.ForEach(b => b.Counter = b == clicked ? b.Counter+1; 0);
}
```

ForEach is a list thing, not a LINQ thing. It's not really any different to a `foreach`, just more compact

You could track the last button clicked as per the other suggestions and it would trade a tiny bit of cpu time saved for a tiny bit of memory used but we're talking about looping 40 buttons - it's nanoseconds

Answer (score 0):

Note that there's no need to reset all the other buttons if the count on the pressed button is not 0, because you can only press one button at a time. Therefore only reset the other buttons if the count == 0.

Furthermore, there's no need to iterate overall the buttons. Track the index of the last pressed button and only reset *that* to 0 when a *different* button is clicked.

(I removed the answer that suggested not to use Linq for memory allocation reasons - that is true on the old compact .NET framework, which did not have generational GC, but probably not relevant any more.)

Answer (score 0):

```
int pressBtnindex = 100;//<-- if you got the button index;

for(int i = 0 ; i < btnList.count();i++)
{
    if(i == pressBtnindex)
    {
        btnList[i].counter++;
        continue;
    }
    btnList[i].counter = 0;
}
```